# CSS elements in inspector displaying wrong code line?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4, web-inspector

[image: dev inspector]

New web dev student here. I'm in inspector looking for certain elements of my web page. However once I find elements, it shows the CSS file and line that it belongs on. But, when I go to the CSS file and look for the element, it's not on that line. Am I missing something here?

Look at both the `.carousel-inner` in the image. Both telling me different lines of code they're on. But when I go to my CSS file in a text editor, those elements are not on the corresponding line that inspector is telling me.

Comment: The bootstrap css is huge. Are you really scrolling to line 6252? Those line numbers may be referring to the other elements (the img and other). Go to the css and do a simple "find" to find .carousel-inner.

Comment: I Ctrl "f"ed it and found the correct ".carousel-inner" element, and I made the correct changes. However once I saved the files and refreshed the site, the inspector still shows that element on the wrong line, with no changes! I even went back to double check that the changes were correctly made and saved.

Comment: In the picture I linked. Why are two exact same elements on different lines? Why does inspector show two identical elements as different elements?

Comment: Did you include more than one `bootstrap.css` file in the document maybe? Different versions of bootstrap? Very hard to tell what the issue is (if there is an actual issue here) but it's on your side and not a bug in the developer tools

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Keep in mind that inside a generated CSS file, there can be several lines for the same definition. What could be happening is that you are checking the definition for the same class, but for a different media query.

I'd suggest you look for all the instances of the definition and see which one reflects the changes.

Comment: I believe this is the case. When I hover over the css file in inspector one states that is is saved locally, and one says its location is https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css:4166. In inspector when I make changes, some changes only properly work when editing the element saved to the long link location. However I only have access to the css file saved locally. Is there a way around this?

Comment: Ok, so you problem is that you are editing something locally, but including a remote file. In this case you are including a file hosted on Bootstrap's MaxCDN. You should change the included file to your local one, that's why your modifications are not being reflected.

Comment: This is definitely the case. However I am unsure on how to include it with my local one.

Comment: The style is normally included in the `<head>` section of your code. You should look for a line similar to: `<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" />` I suggest you search only for `href="https://maxcdn` in case the way it's included is different from the one I mentioned. Then just change the `href` to the one relative to your project.

Comment: Thank you so much! Seems to be exactly what was "wrong".

Answer (score 0):

ctrl+f in your css file should be work

Comment: I Ctrl "f"ed it and found the correct ".carousel-inner" element, and I made the correct changes. However once I saved the files and refreshed the site, the inspector still shows that element on the wrong line, with no changes! I even went back to double check that the changes were correctly made and saved.   
In the picture I linked. Why are two exact same elements on different lines? Why does inspector show two identical elements as different elements

Comment: Bootstrap files are sometimes pre-converted from scss files that may show the line incorrectly or you have not compatible version of this file. for example my own style.css file correctly indicates the lines of the code. This is my opinion so I don't know if this is the true explanation.